# Range undefined for C3 Spline Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, prototypejs, c3.js

I'm trying to modify the behavior of a vertical C3.js Spine chart so that the mousewheel scrolls the range of the data instead of zooming. I created an event listener using Prototype to change the range of the chart when someone scrolls inside its parent div like so:

```
$("chartDiv").observe("mousewheel", function(e,  charts) {
        if (charts.get("splineChart") != null) {
            var cht = charts.get("splineChart");

            var range = cht.axis.range();

            if (e.wheelDelta > 0) {
                cht.axis.range({
                    min: {
                        y: range.min.y - 10
                    },
                    max: {
                        y: range.max.y - 10
                    },
                });
            }
            else {
                cht.axis.range({
                    min: {
                        y: range.min.y + 10
                    },
                    max: {
                        y: range.max.y + 10
                    },
                });
            }
        }
    }.bindAsEventListener(this, chartList));
```

When testing in Chrome, the event is handled corrently and I have access to the chart object that I want to work with, but the max and min objects returned by range() have undefined values for x, y, and y2.

I've read through the API listed on http://c3js.org/reference.html#api-axis-range and it says is that calling range() with no argument should return the current min and max values for each axis.

What am I doing wrong here? I need to get and update the current displayed range for data in the chart.

Comment: C3 doesn't automatically calculate axis min and max values based on the data - you'll have to set these values explicitly to begin with.

Comment: Is there a different method available to get the visible range displayed on the chart then?

Comment: You just have to set an initial y axis max and min from the data set (or bung in a couple of sensible constants). After that it should work ok. See https://jsfiddle.net/rxea1xcy/1/

Comment: Thanks, its working now.